# Compare time values correctly

Tags: mysql, time

I am having trouble comparing MySQL Time fields, I have a NOEVENTS row starting from `09:00` to `10:00` and I am trying to insert a row into another table, but I need to compare the NOEVENTS time, to the incoming Time fields. example:

I want to insert a event from `09:15` to `09:30`, and another from `10:00` to `11:00`, so how can I compare that? im trying this:

```sql
select count(idNOEVENTS) into existNOEVENT from NOEVENTS  b where eventInitialTime && eventFinalTime between b.initialTime and b.finalTime;
if existNOEVENT>0
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error! no events allowed at this time';
```

The problem is when I try to insert the `09:15` to `09:30`, it throws the error message shown above. Thats fine, it works, but when I try to insert the `10:00` to `11:00` event it throw the msg, and it shouldnt, how can  I fix it? or compare it better?

Thanks, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
SELECT *
  FROM noevents
 WHERE (? > initialTime AND ? < finalTime)
    OR (? > initialTime AND ? < finalTime)
```

Now don't use `COUNT(*)` to check for existence of a row(s). Use `EXIST()` instead.

That being said to give an idea this how you procedure code might look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE add_event(IN _start TIME, IN _end TIME)
BEGIN  
  IF EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM noevents
             WHERE (_start > initialTime AND _start < finalTime)
                OR (_end > initialTime AND _end < finalTime)) THEN
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' 
      SET message_text = 'Error! no events allowed at this time';
  ELSE
    -- Do whatever you have to do to insert an event
    SELECT 'Success: event added';
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6edca6/2)** demo